# How do I create a see-through "lint" effect in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, mask, patterns

I want to create a see-through grainy "lint" effect. I've tried all the builtin filters in Adobe Illustrator, but nothing comes even close.

This image shows what I'm looking for. (The different color background is just to show that the "lint marks" are see-through.)

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Where is it failing?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps don't use a filter. Instead find or create a raster image of a texture, and use it as an opacity mask.

For example

[image]

Comment: Wouldn’t that negatively impact scalability?

Comment: @SebastianMeine, not if you make sure to use textures with high enough resolution to account for that.

Comment: Unless i am missing something, you can first image-trace that texture, so it gets converted to vector art, then do what Billy wrote.

Comment: @Lucian - yes, but that might generate thousands of paths depending on the complexity of the raster image, and that could potentially cause its own set of problems.